# Is CategoryList hidden under Calendar at Exchange 2013?

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2013

I am trying to get/update master category list IPM.Configuration.CategoryList and found out I have to create user configuration for it to get linkage to this item in **Exchange 2010**. However, is this still the case in **Exchange 2013**? I mean is this item (CategoryList) still hidden in Exchange 2013? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is still the same on Exchange 2013 and 2016, the only change is currently on Office365 there is a REST Method https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/outlookcategory for setting them that is in Beta. However the underlying storage method is still the same.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and heads-up for the graph api. Another thing is - Can I still delete CategoryList through UserCongiguration.Delete() in Exchange 2013? I was demonstrating what user behaviour auto populates CategoryList, and  found the method works in Exchange 2010 but 2013.

Comment: Yes nothing has changed between versions doing .Delete() just does a DeleteItem operation which is the same for any Exchange Item. I would be suspect on the updates applied to the Exchange server as there where bugs with DeleteItem that where fixed in later Exchange updates

Comment: I appreciate you answering my question, Glen!